Where to handle Validation Errors in Business logic layer?
I'm currently designing a multi-layered application and am trying to figure out the best practice for error handling within the Business Logic Layer (BLL).
Should I handle errors directly within the BLL, or is it better to let them propagate up to the presentation layer?
What are the implications of either approach on maintainability and code clarity?
Are there specific strategies or patterns (like using custom exceptions or a centralized error handling mechanism) that you would recommend for managing errors in the BLL?
I have tried to create custom errors and throw them when something goes wrong in my business logic - like this
const problemWithSameTitle = await this.getByTitle(problemData.title);

if (problemWithSameTitle) {
    throw new ProblemWithSameTitleExists("Problem with the same Title already exists");
}

const createdProblem = await prisma.problem.create({
            data: problemData
        });

return createdProblem;

And handling it in the controller like this
try {
    const problem = await this.problemsService.create(req.body);
    const mappedProblem = new ProblemDto(problem);
    res.status(201).json(new BaseResponseDto(true, 'Problem created successfully', mappedProblem));
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ProblemWithSameTitleExists) {
        res.status(400).json(new BaseResponseDto(false, error.message, null));
    }
}



The business logic layer should throw errors that bubble up and are dealt with at the presentation, or top layer
Validation should be done before you hit the BLL and should return a validation result rather than just throw errors.

So in your example, you should never be sending a new problem to the BLL without first checking that the users form passes validation. ie there isn't a duplicate title. ie
ValidationResult ValidateForm(formdata d)
{
   if(repo.DoesProblemWithTitleExistAlready(d.title))
   {
      return new ValidationResult().Add("title",false,"There already is a problem with this title")
   }
}

App
{
   OnClick()
   {
     if(ValidateForm(form).Errors.Count() == 0)
     {
        SendForm(form) //errors bubble up to global error handler
     }
     else
     {
        ..put red stars and error messages on form
     }
   }
}

Now the BL should still throw an error if the title is a duplicate or some other problem occurs, but this generally wont happen. You can catch it in your global error handler and pop up a dialogue or whatever. Where as the common validation errors aren't exceptional and get special treatment.
The reason to do it this way is to avoid loading down your business logic with complex validation responses at every step. Validation handling will depend on how the application works, not on the business logic. For example you might have human entered data where they need to be told all the things wrong with the form as they type, and a batch load job which is done unattended and just needs a pass/fail written to a log

"Validation should be done before you hit the BLL" Different kinds of validation exist, and this statement is not correct for all of them. When the validation relies on the application of business rules, then the validation definitely belongs in, not before the BLL. UI validation (which would happen before the BLL) is valuable for UX purposes but generally still requires a last line of defense in the BLL if these failures would break the system in any way.

On re-read of my comment, just to be clear: not every validation rule can easily be implemented as a UI validation rule, e.g. when it requires very active coupling to the persistence mechanism or requires some kind of external validation. Some validation makes more sense to put on the BLL alone without a UI validation counterpart.

yeah i think you might be getting into very fine differences in the meaning of "validation" here. what i mean is, just throw errors in the BBL, do the validation in its own class. If you can't, because you have some transactional validation or whatever then do the best you can


I [...] am trying to figure out the best practice for error handling within the Business Logic Layer (BLL).

↑ If that is where you stand, the question below makes no sense. ↓

Should I handle errors directly within the BLL, or is it better to let them propagate up to the presentation layer?

Note: You didn't specify what kind errors.
Each error kind should be handled in the appropriate layer. E.g. business logic errors should be handled in the business logic layer. Technical errors like converting a user input string to a number should be handled in the presentation layer.
As an optimization you might end up with business errors being also handled in the presentation layer. But keep in mind that this is code duplication for optimization. It comes with it's problems.

What are the implications of either approach on maintainability and code clarity?

This question should disappear giving that each error handling is in the error-related layer.
If you decide to do error handling in the wrong layer, you'll have unwanted dependencies and incomplete error handling logic.

Are there specific strategies or patterns (like using custom exceptions or a centralized error handling mechanism) that you would recommend for managing errors in the BLL?

(Personal Opinion:) I would use object-like structures for errors in the BLL (example: exceptions, error-objects - depending on how you want to handle errors).
Reason: BLL errors are most likely to contain comparably a lot of context information. This can quickly become difficult to handle in anything else but object-like structures.
